# How to correctly setup load balancer in ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-deployment, amazon-ecs, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have 3 services that I need to deploy: an API on port 80, a dashboard on port 3333 and a webpage on port 3000.

I'm using ECS and created a cluster. For my API I created a task definition and a service pointing to a load balancer. Everything works fine.

Now I need to deploy also the dashboard and web page: do I need to create a load balancer for each service?

I saw that by creating a task definition for my dashboard everything was working fine, but I couldn't create a custom address (dashboard.example.com) for that service since in Route 53 I'm able to link a URL only to the load balancer.

So now I've created a new load balancer only for the dashboard service and everything is working fine (well I have some problem with the ports, but still it seems to work fine).

So my question is: is it correct what I'm doing? It is normal to have a load balancer for each service or it is too much? Or should I stick with one load balancer for the entire cluster and find a different way to assign addresses to my services?

Comment: You can have one LB with multiple Target Groups (one for each service). This would require different ports, but it seems your services all run on different ports already. Have you tried that?

Comment: But how can I assign adresses then if I can only assign them to load balancer instances?

Comment: You can have multiple domains on a single LB. Based on the `Host header` you could create listener rules to redirect to different TGs.